# How can I find out if a word is in a given sentence?

Tags: javascript

I want to find out if a certain word is in a given sentence. If yes, then I want to return true, if not, then return false.

For example:

word = "big"

sentence 1: "Tom is my big brother."

This should return `true`.

sentence 2: "Sandra is very old."

This should return `false`.

sentence 3: "Ralph is the biggest."

This should return `true`.

How can I find out if a word is in a given sentence?

Comment: `sentence.includes(word)`

Comment: What about "The answer is ambiguous"? True or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built in string method to find out a *substring* (word) in the given *string* (sentence).

The includes() method can be used to determine if a string is present inside other string, returning true or false.

Usage:

If you are using ES6 you can use the `includes` method:

```
'a nice string'.includes('nice') //true
 const isPresent = sentence.includes(word)  //returns Boolean values
```

If you are not using ES6, you can use the `indexOf` method:

```
'a nice string'.indexOf('nice') !== -1 //true
```